# Mocking a simple function (and not activity) in a Go Temporal Workflow using testSuite.NewTestWorkflowEnvironment()

Tags: go, mocking, temporal-workflow

I have a bunch of temporal workflows and have mocked all activities successfully in them.

```
env := testSuite.NewTestWorkflowEnvironment()
env.OnActivity(someActivity, mock.Anything, mock.Anything).Return(MockSameActivity)
```

However, using such a test environment, I am not able to mock a simple method call as there is no utility method provided here: https://pkg.go.dev/go.temporal.io/temporal/internal

The design is
workflow starts
bunch of activities run (which are mocked)
workflow exits
Some helper method from another package is executed <-- I need help in mocking this.

Could someone help?